# c# mvc4 Html.DropDownListFor calling the controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have browsed through several posts and several codes and none of them seems to work.

I need to reload a WebGrid based on a DropDown selected key on same page, partial views. I am now building the dropdown element and using this code in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Users, Model.Users, 
                                         new { autopostback = "true" })
```

Along with the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select:[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox]:[autopostback=true],input[type=radio]:[autopostback=true]')
      .live('change',function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Javascript Console at browser says:

```
Uncaught Error:Syntax error, unrecognized expression:select:[autopostback=true],
         input[type=checkbox]:[autopostback=true],
         input[type=radio]:[autopostback=true]
```

No calls are being done at Controller. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

As this is now working, here goes what IS working so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#UserList").change(function (e) {
            var _this = $(this);

            $.post("@Url.Action("List","MainController", Model)", _this.closest("form").serialize(),
                                                             function (response) {
                                                                 // do something with response.
                                                             });
  });
```

And the View:

```
                <td class="tdatadata">@Html.DropDownList("UserList", Model.Users, new { autopostback = "true" })</td>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
public class ModelViewModel
{
    public int idSelected { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuários Cadastrados")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
```

But I still have a problem: How to pass the selected field to the controller action ? I tried using DropDownListFor, but in that case I loose the object name and them the Jscript does not work.

Comment: why are you using such a huge selector you can just use id

Comment: Would you be kind to tell me how to use id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox][autopostback=true],input[type=radio][autopostback=true]').live('change',function () {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Remove column ":" from the selector which is a meta character and makes the selector invalid, also you don't need them.

EIther try to use id or to get all the input fields of the form use [jquery :input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) `$('form :input')` to select all the input fields of the form.

i.e

```
$('form').find(':input').live('change',function () {
     $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
});
```

*Also note that live has been deprecated and if you are using jquery version >=1.7 use on() instead of live*

Comment: Thanks PSL for help. Did the changes and still npt working. Getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' error from Javasctipt console. Can you please put the full view code. Thanks.

Comment: Use on instead of live as I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Mendez live has been deprecated in newer versions of jquery. here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/tjSmu/

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `:` and change `.live` by `.on`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[autopostback=true],input[type=checkbox][autopostback=true],input[type=radio][autopostback=true]').on('change',function () {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```